# Не вызывается метод shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты

Версия React 16.9.0. При обновлении props-ов не вызывается метод shouldComponentUpdate. При этом отлично работает метод componentDidUpdate и componentWillUpdate.

```
class Component extends React.Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate( nextProps, nextState ) {
        console.log( 'shouldComponentUpdate' );
        return true;
    }

    componentWillUpdate( ) {
        console.log( 'componentWillUpdate' );
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log( 'componentDidUpdate' );
    }

    render() {
        console.log( 'isInited', this.props.isInited );
        ...
    }

}
```

В консоли:

> isInited false
>
> componentWillUpdate
>
> isInited true
>
> componentDidUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Проверил на React v16.9.0 работу Вашего кода, передал одну пропсу и изменил ее. Всё отработало как нужно, пример кода:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
    return true;
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log('componentWillUpdate');
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
  }

  render() {
    console.log('isInited', this.props.isInited);
    return <div > It works... < /div>;
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isInited: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isInited: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Child isInited={this.state.isInited} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Сссылки на React v16.9.0 брал из официальной документации: [React v16.9.0](https://ru.reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/08/react-v16.9.0.html#react)

Прикреплю на всякий случай ссылки на документацию:

- [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)
- [`UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate)
- [`componentDidUpdate`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Есть подозрения, что Вы что-то делаете не так. Метод `shouldComponentUpdate` не вызывается при первом рендере или когда используется `forceUpdate()`. Может Вы использовали `forceUpdate()` в своем коде. Необходимо пройти по всему коду и найти причину *"магического"* поведения. Из коробки всё работает как нужно, предоставленный пример наглядно это демонстрирует:

Также, есть некоторые подозрения на React Redux, исходя из следующей документации: [Return Values Determine If Your Component Re-Renders](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#return-values-determine-if-your-component-re-renders) где говорится о том, что React Redux внутренне реализует метод `shouldComponentUpdate`. Я бы проверил эту теорию, но не исключаю человеческий фактор ошибки, например возвращение измененного объекта с той же ссылкой является распространенной ошибкой, которая может привести к тому, что ваш компонент не будет повторно визуализироваться, как ожидается (об этом также говорится в ссылке выше).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может Redux вызывает forceUpdate? Св-во isInited передаёт родительский компонент, который подключён к стору. И это св-во в сторе меняется по результату AJAX запроса.

Comment: @Артур Вы ведь значение получаете через `mapStateToProps`, берете значение из хранилища и присваиваете в пропсы компонента. Не думаю, что там юзается `forceUpdate` - это очень нелогично. Или у Вас какой-то иной механизм получения пропсов?

Comment: Именно он:   export default connect( state => ({ ...state.app }) )( App );

Comment: @Артур Redux внутренне реализует метод `shouldComponentUpdate` - значит есть вероятность, что что-то пошло не так именно из-за него. Попробуйте простым способом обновить пропсу и посмотрите на результат. В данный момент нет проекта под рукой, где был бы развернут Redux.

Comment: @Артур spread syntax гарантирует нам, что будет новый объект со скопированными пропертями, значит ошибочное поведение из-за ссылки можно вычеркнуть. Остается проверить теорию о том, что Redux не позволяет дернуть `shouldComponentUpdate `

Comment: Да, однако, если работать просто со State у родительского компонента, то метод срабатывает, а если через Redux, даже не используя AJAX, а сразу dispatch-нуть метод смены значения в Store, то хрен.

Comment: @Артур Redux реализует метод `shouldComponentUpdate` таким образом, что он делает поверхностное сравнение `props` и `state`. То есть, в теории, если мы реализуем свой метод  `shouldComponentUpdate`, то попадать мы в него всё же должны... но не попадаем. Я не нашел в документации фразы, где говорится, что метод не вызовется. Я бы предположил, что будет два вызова, один в Redux, а другой у нас. Но почему-то это работает не так, как ожидается. Вывод прост - виноват Redux со своей реализацией `shouldComponentUpdate`. Что для меня до сих пор кажется странным.

Comment: Эх, нужно в потомке вызвать загрузку данных после того, как прошла инициализация приложение. И это лучше всего по моему было делать в shouldComponentUpdate вернув fasle, дабы лишний раз не перерисовывать. Но наверное придётся этим заниматься в componentDidUpdate после повторной отрисовки.